# php considers numeric value as empty string (weird behavior)

Tags: php, variables

This is my own code that has confused for more than 2 hours.

```
$int_length_1 = $data[0]['length_1'];   // length_1 is mysql integer field

print_result(array('difference' => $data[0]['length_1'], 'object' => 'line'));

$int_length_2 = $data[0]['length_2'];   // length_2 is mysql integer field

print_result(array('difference' => $int_length_2, 'object' => 'line'));

print_result(array('difference' => ($data[0]['length_1'] - $data[0]['length_2']), 'object' => 'line'));

function print_result($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        if (isset($data['difference']) && $data['difference'] != '') {
            echo 'Current length of the '.$data['object'].' is '.$data['difference'].'<br>';
        }       
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
Current length of the line is 10
Current length of the line is 7
Current length of the line is 3
```

but somehow, the code only prints the first 2 lines.

is there something wrong with the code? does this have anything to do with data type comparison?

thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Try casting your lengths to integers, i.e. $int_length_2 = (int)$data[0]['length_2'];. This is needed if your MySQL driver returns ints as strings (which is unexpected, and is thus standard practice in the PHP world).

Comment: @Tibo done that already and nothing's changed

Comment: Check http://codepad.viper-7.com/YtUTFe, it prints 3 lines normally.

Comment: Try to replace for a moment the echo with this: "echo 'example';" just to understand if, in your case, the function is called or not.

Comment: OK, but what if you used the typecasted value in your subtraction ? print_result(array('difference' => $int_length_1 - $int_length_2), 'object' => 'line'));

Comment: @xdazz, i just gave it a try and assigned $int_length_1 and $int_length_2 with 9 and 6. it prints 3 lines as expected. but i if return to $data[0]['length_1'] and $data[0]['length_2'], it prints only 2.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: it is called.

Comment: @dqiu Could you show the result of `var_dump($data[0])`?

Comment: @xdazz: 


array(9) { ["object_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["length_1"]=> string(1) "45" ["length_2"]=> string(1) "22" ["status_id"]=> string(1) "0" }
array(9) { ["object_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["length_1"]=> string(1) "28" ["data_quantity"]=> string(1) "23" ["status_id"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: @dqiu Check the data, can php will not lie to you.

Comment: @xdazz: do you mean var_dump-ing shows length_1 and length_2 as string?

Comment: @dqiu No, you did `var_dump` twice?

Comment: @xdazz uhm, yes, i think i did

Answer (score 0):

Try type casting and see if the results are the same

`$int_length_1 = (int) $data[0]['length_1'];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but I just happened to come across it today and decided to see what's up with it.

Code I was running:

```
<?php

$data = array(array('length_1'=>10, 'length_2'=>10)); 

/*  OUTPUT for array(array('length_1'=>10, 'length_2'=>7));   

      Current length of the line is 10
      Current length of the line is 7
      Current length of the line is 3 
*/

/*  OUTPUT for array(array('length_1'=>10, 'length_2'=>10));   

      Current length of the line is 10
      Current length of the line is 10
      difference == ''
*/

$int_length_1 = $data[0]['length_1'];   // length_1 is mysql integer field

print_result(array('difference' => $data[0]['length_1'], 'object' => 'line'));

$int_length_2 = $data[0]['length_2'];   // length_2 is mysql integer field

print_result(array('difference' => $int_length_2, 'object' => 'line')); 

// this is where weird things start to happen 
// if ($data[0]['length_1'] - $data[0]['length_2']) === 0 
print_result(array('difference' => ($data[0]['length_1'] - $data[0]['length_2']), 'object' => 'line'));

function print_result($data) 
{
    if (is_array($data)) 
    {
        //  I added some conditional statements to see why OP 
        //   wasn't getting that third output. 
        if (isset($data['difference']) && $data['difference'] != '') {
            echo 'Current length of the '.$data['object'].' is '.$data['difference'].'<br>';
        }   
        else if (!isset($data['difference'])) {
            print "difference is not set"; 
        }
        else if ( $data['difference'] == '') {
            print "difference == ''"; 
        }
    }
}

?>
```

if you change this line:

```
if (isset($data['difference']) && $data['difference'] != '') {
```

to do a `!==` instead of just `!=`, the code works as expected and returns all three lines of expected output.

This is how `0` and an empty string relate:

```
$zero = 0;

if (empty($zero)) print "empty(0) \n"; else print "!empty(0) \n";
if ($zero=='')    print "0=='' \n";    else print "0!='' \n";
if ($zero==='')   print "0==='' \n";   else print "0!=='' \n";
if ($zero==0)     print "0==0 \n";     else print "0!=0 \n";
if ($zero===0)    print "0===0 \n";    else print "0!==0 \n";
if (strlen($zero)==0) print "strlen(0)==0 \n"; else print "strlen(0)!=0 \n";

print "\n\n"; 
$string = '';

if (empty($string)) print "empty('') \n"; else print "!empty('') \n";
if ($string=='')    print "''=='' \n";    else print "''!='' \n";
if ($string==='')   print "''==='' \n";   else print "''!=='' \n";
if ($string==0)     print "''==0 \n";     else print "''!=0 \n";
if ($string===0)    print "''===0 \n";    else print "''!==0 \n";
if (strlen($string)==0) print "strlen('')==0 \n"; else print "strlen('')!=0 \n";
```

And the output:

```
empty(0) 
0=='' 
0!=='' 
0==0 
0===0 
strlen(0)!=0 


empty('') 
''=='' 
''==='' 
''==0 
''!==0 
strlen('')==0
```

So.. basically... OP should have used a `===` to make sure everything was working as he expected.